# Pegar o retorno JSON e passar para uma variável PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso passar a variável de retorno dentro do `alert` e passar para PHP, porém tudo que estou tentando de exemplos atá aqui, mesmo do fórum, está dando erro de JavaScript:

```
<?php
 $pegar_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
?>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io/<?=$pegar_ip;?>/json", function(dados) {              

            alert (dados.loc);

        });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usando **file_get_contents** veja como fica:

```
<?php
    $pegar_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $json_url = "https://ipinfo.io/".$pegar_ip."/json";
    $json     = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json     =str_replace('},

        ]',"}

        ]",$json);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Os dados vão estar dentro na variável `$data`

Comment: Solução poerfeita @samuel, obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro você usar CURL segue o meu código de exemplo:

```html
<?php

 $url = "https://api.ipify.org/";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $ip = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);


 $url = "https://ipinfo.io/".$ip."/json";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 print $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O PHP e o JavaScript não conseguem se comunicar, então eu sugiro você tentar fazer um `innerHTML` com a variável dentro de um `input` e então usar `$_GET` ou `$_POST` para puxá-lo para o PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function teste()
 {
     var teste = 5;
     document.GetElementById("variavel").innerHTML ='<input type="hidden" name="valor" value="'+teste+'">'; 
 }
<body>
<form>
<div id="variavel">
</div>
</form>

 <?php
    $varTeste=$_GET['valor'];
 ?>
```